# Image classification history in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, classification

I would like to examine the details for a supervised classification project performed previously in ArcGIS Pro. Specifically, I am interested in the segmentation characteristics used (spectral and spatial detail, etc.).

Is there a way to view this in history?

I can't find a record of it in the project raster function history pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has been recorded then look at the geoprocessing log in the metadata (what esri confusingly call item description). This will hold the vital parameter information that you seek. You may need to adjust the style of metadata to see this information as the default is just a bare bones description; this you do through options under the Project tab.